# Model could not be saved

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, seq2seq

```
class Seq2Seq(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, enc_v_dim, dec_v_dim, emb_dim, units, attention_layer_size, max_pred_len, start_token,
                 end_token):
        super().__init__()
        self.units = units

        ....

    def encode(self, x):
        o = self.enc_embeddings(x)
        init_s = [tf.zeros((x.shape[0], self.units)), tf.zeros((x.shape[0], self.units))]
       ...
        return s

    def inference(self, x, return_align=False):
         ... 
         return pred_id

    def train_logits(self, x, y, seq_len):
        ...
        return logits

    def step(self, x, y, seq_len):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = self.train_logits(x, y, seq_len)
            dec_out = y[:, 1:]  # ignore <GO>
            loss = self.cross_entropy(dec_out, logits)
            grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
        self.opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_variables))
        return loss
```

I found a model for natural language processing that works well and trained well. But I don't know how to save it, it's different from the typical model structure I've seen, and I can't call functions like build or compile. I would like to know how can I save such a model.

Comment: does `model.save('path')` work?

Comment: if i use model.compile()

Comment: but the model saved can not be load correctment